# RegEx for capturing a string of characters at the same time

Tags: regex, filter, substring, regexp-substr

I need to create a filter based on regex (Regular Expression). Here is the example:

It is mandatory to create a filter which can filter both of these two data file names:

```
ZVSEBACTAA.PACS_.0230.[YYYYMMDDhhmmss].[Q5].EBA.S202SCTAAAAAAAA.I
ZVSEBADD11.PACS_.0230.[YYYYMMDDhhmmss].[Q5].EBA.S202COR11111111.I
```

To include all the sentence for both of them, we have this regex (already done):

```
(^(ZVSEBACT|ZVSEBADD)[A-Z,0-9]{2}\.PACS_\.0230\.)(.*)\.EBA\.(S202(SCT|COR))([A-Z,0-9]{8})\.I$
```

However, I need to find out one filter for filtering just from AAAAAAAA (8 lengh string of characters overall), but also can be substitute by 11111111 (the same lengh too, but in this case by numbers), in all cases, the total 8 characters can be a number or character interchangeable.

The filter I created (used Notepad++ as coding tool):

```
([A-Z,0-9]{8})\.I$
```

This means that I want to filter a string of characters with 8 lengh, but my doubt is at the end, I do not know how to only get selected up to the latest A (or 1), to cover AAAAAAAAA in the first row, and 11111111 in the second row.

After creating the filter, should be selected AAAAAAAAA, and 11111111, but actually is select AAAAAAAAAA.I and 11111111.I in each of them.

```
ZVSEBACTAA.PACS_.0230.[YYYYMMDDhhmmss].[Q5].EBA.S202SCTAAAAAAAA.I
ZVSEBADD11.PACS_.0230.[YYYYMMDDhhmmss].[Q5].EBA.S202COR11111111.I
```

No errors or warnings but should skip the end (.I), expect to cover just the 8 mentioned positions.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/TPpvRe/1) what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said you are using Notepad++, here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^ZVSEB(?:ACT|ADD)[A-Z0-9]{2}\.PACS_\.0230\..+?\.EBA\.S202(?:SCT|COR)\K[A-Z0-9]{8}(?=\.I$)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
ZVSEB               # literally
(?:ACT|ADD)         # non capture group, ACT or ADD
[A-Z0-9]{2}         # 2 uppercase or digit
\.PACS_\.0230\.     # literally
.+?                 # 1 or more any character, not greedy
\.EBA\.S202         # literally
(?:SCT|COR)         # non capture group, SCT or COR
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
[A-Z0-9]{8}         # 8 uppercase or digit
(?=\.I$)            # positive lookahead, make sure we have after: .I then end of line
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TPpvRe/1)

Comment: Thank you very much Toto, its working fine! I already check it: (?=\.I$) at the end of the regex and is over.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of regex you're using (there are a few different ones) you should be able to use a positive lookahead instead of capturing the text at the end.

For example:

```
(\b(ZVSEBACT|ZVSEBADD)[A-Z,0-9]{2}\.PACS_\.0230\.)(.*?)\.EBA\.(S202(SCT|COR))([A-Z,0-9]{8})(?=\.I\b)
```

A couple of things I changed:

The character `.` in regex is a wildcard, so I've made them `\.` in places it appears you're actually looking for a `.` character.
The text I copy/pasted from above pasted in on a single line, so I've changed the ^ and $ to \b (word boundaries) which allows multiple matches on the same line to match both the numbers.

The addition of `(?=\.I\b)` looks forwards (after the capture) to ensure that the next characters are `.I` followed by the end of the word (ie, end of the document or a space, etc) without capturing them.

Try it out on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PZWxr7/3) and let me know if that's not what you wanted!

Comment: Hi Jamie, thanks for your answer and explanation. Yes, this is another alternative solution. Instead of using ^ in the beginning, using \b in the beginning and in the end.